# Python Serialized JSON in a c# class with Newtonsoft

Tags: python, c#, json, serialization

I have this program which gives me a json in python.

```
from Kalos_Word2Vec import WordVecFramework
from sys import argv
from json import dumps

def extractword(w,text):
    path = r"C:\Users\GAMING\Desktop\Kalos_Python\Training Data\Word2Vec_Gensim.model"
    f = w.returnvectorGPU(path,text)
    return f

def cleanup(w):
    f = w.delmodelGPU()

text = argv[1]

#Format Text
#text = "[nice Love this]"
text = text.replace(".","")
text = text.replace("[","")
text = text.replace("]","")
text = text.lower()

#Split it into words
wor = text.split(' ')
w = WordVecFramework()

#Extract words
jsons = []

for i in wor:
    jas = extractword(w,i)
    jsons.append((i,jas))

print(dumps(jsons))
```

I Get the Json and then try to deserialize it

```
public static async Task<WordVector[]> ExtractSentenceComplete(Kalos_VirtualAssistant main, string sentence)
                {
                    //Get Bi String
                    string bi = FormatBiString(sentence);

                    //Get base Python Script
                    PythonScript ba = PythonUtility.FindScript(main.PythonHub.Scripts, "Vector");
                    PythonScript sr = FormatScript(bi, ba);

                    //Run
                    string result = await CallPythonScript(main, sr);
                    KDebug.Log(result);

                    //Serialize JSON
                    WordVector[] vectors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WordVector[]>(result);

                    return vectors;
                }
```

But I get this error from newtonsoft.

*JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Kalos.Language.v2.Word2Vec.Extraction.Py.WordVector' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (System.Collections.IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object existingValue, System.String id) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) (at <7ca8898b690a4181a32a9cf767cedb1e>:0)
Kalos.Language.v2.Word2Vec.Extraction.Py.Kalos_W2V_ExtractionGen1+d__10.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scenes/Kalos_VirtualAssistant.cs:2985)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
Kalos.Main.Kalos_VirtualAssistant+d__40.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scenes/Kalos_VirtualAssistant.cs:437)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)*

I guess its a problem with how Python and c# handle json but how should I fix this?
Here's My class in c#

```
public class WordVector
            {
                public float[] weights { get; set; }

                public string json { get; set; }

                public WordVectorResult WordVectorResult { get; set; }

                public WordVector(float[] weights, WordVectorResult result, string json)
                {
                    this.weights = weights;
                    this.WordVectorResult = result;
                    this.json = json;
                }

                public WordVector(WordVectorResult result)
                {
                    this.WordVectorResult = result;
                }
            }
```

Hope I can get a solution for this.
I'm using .NET Standard 2.0.
Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: Don't know Python well, but I'm sure you're not supposed to try build JSON yourself, that's a recipe for disaster. Use a library function. What is the actual JSON value?

Comment: [["nice", "[-0.37469643354415894, 0.17531715333461761, -0.15691688656806946, 0.4300050437450409, 0.22246809303760529, 0.023539,-0.3806658387184143, -0.004344320856034756, -0.2850494086742401, -0.20899416506290436, -0.5081614255905151, 0.39551275968551636, -0.24039819836616516, -0.23005953431129456, -0.6259180307388306, 0.30508261919021606, -0.006120555568486452, -0.08991122990846634, 0.3006988763809204, -0.09339240193367004, -0.4708925485610962, -0.12479282915592194, -0.17402227222919464, -0.2933194041252136, -0.09514305740594864, 0.1740504503250122, 0.08480750024318695, -0.0643598884344101]"]

Comment: It's an array within an array, so you need to deserialize `YourObject[][]`. The object has a single property `nice` so I'm not sure how any of the properties in `WordVector` are relevant